# azure ftp to dropbox connector not working in a logic app

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps

I figured the below out about an hour after posting.
There are not many examples out there yet so I left this up.

I am trying to setup a new connector in a Azure Logic App to get files from a FTP site and move them to a dropbox folder.

I was not even getting TO the dropbox part, although it was finding the FTP site and then deleting files.

I have a test directory called testing off of:
ftp://eek.myftpsite.com/testing/

I am obviously not understanding something fundamental to this process here.
I have attached a picture of the ftp connector and it action.
[image]
Here is the code for the trigger:

```
   "operation": "TriggerOnFileAvailable",
            "parameters": {
                "triggerState": "@coalesce(triggers()?.outputs?.body?['triggerState'], '')",
                "FolderPath": "testing",
                "FileMask": "CSV*",
                "FileType": "Text"
```

And the code for the action (this part turned out to be not needed):

```
   "operation": "GetFile",
            "parameters": {
                "FilePath": "@{triggers().outputs.body.FilePath}",
                "FileType": "Text"
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "Raw",
                "scheme": "Zumo",
```

When I drop a file named CSV_test2.txt with one line of text in it in the ftp folder, after a short bit it is removed - as expected.
If I go to the trigger history it shows it fired successfully.
The outputs from the trigger looks correct as well (turns out it was):

```
  "body": {
    "FileName": "CSV_test2.txt",
    "FolderPath": "testing",
    "FilePath": "testing\\CSV_test2.txt",
    "ServerAddress": "eek.myftpsite.com",
    "Content": "This is the data in the test file.",
    "ContentTransferEncoding": "None",
    "triggerState": "CSV_test2.txt"
}
```

But if I go to the actions it shows as failed (because I had the wrong next step, it should have just been something that takes a filepath, like dropbox).
The inputs for the actions show:

```
   "operation": "GetFile",
"parameters": {
    "FilePath": "testing\\CSV_test2.txt",
    "FileType": "Text"
},
"apiVersion": "2015-01-14",
"authentication": {
    "scheme": "Zumo",
    "type": "Raw"
}
```

Which seems like it is correct to me (nope).
The outputs shows:

```
    },
"body": {
    "status": 404,
    "source": "https://ftpconnectora4cf805ee5114235ad1c43445a153673.azurewebsites.net/file/testing/CSV_test2.txt?FileType=Text",
    "message": "Path does not exist on FTP Server. The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."
}
```

I have tried every combination of things I can think of, including just hardcoding the path and file name -- all to no avail.
I am really wanting to try to get this working on a new project vs doing it the "old" way.

Any suggestions are welcome,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a misunderstanding of how it worked.
I thought you setup a FTP connector and which would then monitor for new files, then you setup another FTP action to get each new file.
A bit of over thinking on my part it turns out.

Nope, just feed the output directly like this:

[image]

The code for it is:

```
 "operation": "UploadFile",
            "parameters": {
                "FilePath": "@{triggers().outputs.body.FilePath}",
                "content": {
                    "Content": "@{triggers().outputs.body.Content}",
                    "ContentTransferEncoding": "None"
                },
                "overwrite": true
```

Pretty cool...I am leaving my muddling about up there in the hopes that it helps somebody else out.  This is all pretty new stuff, but pretty exciting.

Thank you,

Joe