# Azure FTP connector to Dropbox not working

Tags: azure, ftp

Trying to set up an Azure Logic App to get files from a FTP site and to a dropbox folder.

Once created, the FTP connector does not appear to pick up files from my ftp despite the fact that I have checked that the proper creds are there and I can access from filezilla. I have checked and aligned resource groups and have replicated the code from a successful solution from a previous post.  [Relevant Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550016/azure-ftp-to-dropbox-connector-not-working-in-a-logic-app)

I'm sure I'm not understanding something basic here.

[Here is the code for the triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdr46.jpg)

[and the code for the actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMKWK.jpg)

Comment: In addition - there is nothing working  - I don't even see a request being sent

Comment: It appears to be making requests with no errors when i look at the FTP connector outside of the logic app

Comment: Add your comment to post (edit), and try to past some relevant code.